# How would you find the expected molecular orbital energy diagram for compounds such as NO?

Tags: electrons

How would you find the expected molecular orbital energy diagram for $\ce{NO}$? Would it be the expected one for $\ce{O2}$? Or the one for $\ce{N2}$? Also, would the ionization energy be bigger than that of$\ce{NO+}$?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange. Try looking in one of many standard textbooks on physical chemistry and on inorganic chemistry then seek out more specialist books on molecular structure. Wikipedia has a page with some diagrams you could use as a start.